# Is it possible to have a list of generic instance?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lambda

I have three objects that contain some fields, but two of the fields are start date and end date.

I have another Wrapper class that contains two fields (startDate and endDate) and a constructor.

I want to create a generic method that accepts ObjectA, ObjectB, ObjectC and returns me a list of times containing the start date, end date.

Is there a better way to make it more dynamic?

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TimeIntervalObj {

    private Timestamp startDate;
    private Timestamp endDate;

    public static List<TimeIntervalObj> constructTimeIntervals(List<?> arrayList) {
        if (arrayList instanceof ObjectA) {
            return arrayList.stream()
                    .map(ObjectA.class::cast)
                    .map(time -> new TimeIntervalObj(time.getStartDate(), time.getEndDate())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        } else if (arrayList instanceof ObjectB) {
            return arrayList.stream()
                    .map(ObjectB.class::cast)
                    .map(time -> new TimeIntervalObj(time.getStartDate(), time.getEndDate())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        } else if (arrayList instanceof ObjectC) {
            return arrayList.stream()
                    .map(ObjectC.class::cast)
                    .map(time -> new TimeIntervalObj(time.getStartDate(), time.getEndDate())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Instance Error Type Incompatibility");
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any chance to change `ObjectA`, `ObjectB` and `ObjectC` to just implement a newly created `HasStartAndEndDate` interface? (oh, and as you noticed your `instanceof` checks **definitely** don't work the way you sketched it, as you're checking the `List` itself and not each members).

Comment: As a side-note: if you're on Java 17 or later (technically 14, but 17 is the LTS release) then you should investigate replacing the lombok annotations with plain old java `record` classes, which do most of that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clean way would be to introduce a new interface that defines the `getStartDate()` and `getEndDate()` method and make `ObjectA`, `ObjectB` and `ObjectC` implement it:

```
public interface HasStartAndEndDate {
    Timestamp getStartDate();
    Timestamp getEndDate();
}
```

Then your method could simply be:

```
public static List<TimeIntervalObj> constructTimeIntervals(Collection<? extends HasStartAndEndDate> arrayList) {
    return arrayList.stream()
            .map(time -> new TimeIntervalObj(time.getStartDate(), time.getEndDate()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

If that's not feasible for some reason (most likely because any one of the classes are not under your control), then you might have to check each objects type individually:

```
public static List<TimeIntervalObj> constructTimeIntervals(Collection<?> collection) {
    return collection.stream()
            .map(TimeIntervalObj::from)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static TimeIntervalObj from(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof ObjectA a) {
        return new TimeIntervalObj(a.getStartDate(), a.getEndDate());
    } else if (o instanceof ObjectB b) {
        return new TimeIntervalObj(b.getStartDate(), b.getEndDate());
    } else if (o instanceof ObjectC c) {
        return new TimeIntervalObj(c.getStartDate(), c.getEndDate());
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported type: " + o.getClass());
}
```

The two approaches can also be combined, if you want all classes under your control to use the interface and other classes to also be supported (let's pretend `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` now implement the interface, but `ObjectC` still doesn't):

```
public static List<TimeIntervalObj> constructTimeIntervals(Collection<?> collection) {
    return collection.stream()
            .map(TimeIntervalObj::from)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static TimeIntervalObj from(HasStartAndEndDate hsed) {
    return new TimeIntervalObj(hsed.getStartDate(), hsed.getEndDate());
}

public static TimeIntervalObj from(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof HasStartAndEndDate hsed) {
        return from(hsed);
    } else if (o instanceof ObjectC c) {
        return new TimeIntervalObj(c.getStartDate(), c.getEndDate());
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported type: " + o.getClass());
}
```

Note that the extra `from(HasStartEndDate)` method is not strictly necessary (and won't be directly called in `constructTimeIntervals` as the compiler will understand that the argument is of type `Object`), but it's better to avoid the `instanceof` shenanigans in the cases where the static type is known (for example if you directly call `TimeIntervalObj.from(someKnownObjectThatImplementsHasStartEndDate)` elsewhere in your code).

Comment: Very clean solution!

Answer (score 3):

Make the `ObjectA`, `ObjectB`, and `ObjectC` implement the same interface.

```
interface MyObject {
    Timestamp getStartDate();
    Timestamp getEndDate();
}
```

Then the Stream pipeline becomes simple.

```
return arrayList.stream()
        .filter(MyObject.class::isInstance)
        .map(MyObject.class::cast)
        .map(time -> new TimeIntervalObj(time.getStartDate(), time.getEndDate()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

If, however, each of the `ObjectA`, `ObjectB`, and `ObjectC` objects require a different mapping to `TimeIntervalObj` object, the newer Java versions offer a solution with sealed classes and switch expressions:

```
sealed interface MyObject permits ObjectA, ObjectB, ObjectC { }
```

```
@Data
final class ObjectA implements MyObject {
    Timestamp startDate1;
    Timestamp endDate1;
}

@Data
final class ObjectB implements MyObject {
    Timestamp startDate2;
    Timestamp endDate2;
}

@Data
final class ObjectC implements MyObject {
    Timestamp startDate3;
    Timestamp endDate3;
}
```

```
private static TimeIntervalObj map(MyObject object) {
    return switch (object) {
        case ObjectA a -> new TimeIntervalObj(a.getStartDate1(), a.getEndDate1());
        case ObjectB b -> new TimeIntervalObj(b.getStartDate2(), b.getEndDate2());
        case ObjectC c -> new TimeIntervalObj(c.getStartDate3(), c.getEndDate3());
    };
}
```

```
return arrayList.stream()
        .filter(MyObject.class::isInstance)
        .map(object -> map((MyObject) object))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Implementation note:** You can use Java 17 with the enabled preview for newer features. Otherwise, all you are left is to use a simple if-else branching with the `instanceof` operator.

Comment: Pattern matching in case is a preview feature in Java 19. Personally I wouldn't yet advertise it like this.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Correct, I think it's fair to add a note.